# is there a race condition in this javascript?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, concurrency

In the following js snippet

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true)
request.send()

request.onload = function() {
  data = JSON.parse(this.response)
}
```

should the assignment of the on load be before the send() to avoid a race condition. Or does the browser deal with it for you (by firing the on load when you get round to assigning it).

Comment: JavaScript is fundamentally single-threaded, so no, there's no race condition.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm pretty sure the browser won't initiate the request until after the browser's thread is free. But I'm not sure if that's specified behavior. I suppose it's possible some browsers may implement this differently.

Comment: It's at least considered good practice to place the event handlers before the `open()` and `send()` calls to make it sure it's not an issue, even if the chances are slim for a race condition, it's so easy to make sure you avoid it.

Comment: You shouldn't use onload. Use `onreadystatechange`, testing for `request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request should look more like:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
request.open('GET', '/my/url');
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
     console.log(request.responseText);
  }
}
request.send();
```

To further answer your question `request.send()` should happen last, because if the response comes back before the function is assigned to `request.onreadystatechange`, there could be a problem, although it's very unlikely that the response would be that fast.

Comment: I'm pretty in most JavaScript implementations it's simply *not possible* to get a response back before the event is bound because the events are only fired when there's nothing left for it to run. Also, I don't think the `ActiveXObject` hack is necessary since IE8+; maybe earlier.

Comment: The function assigned to `request.onreadystatechange` is fired when the `readyState` changes. `request.send()`, just sends your url info to the server, since this is a `'GET'` request.

Comment: I'm not sure what/if that has to do with what I just said, or how onreadystatechange + readystate==4 differs from request.onload. It appears onload is fired immediately after readyState change. http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/DJY5G/4/

Comment: `onload` is not standard for `XMLHttpRequest`s. Think Progressive Enhancement.